# How to display date-time in HH:MM AM format in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a date string "2017-01-19 10:34:36", it's coming from API.

I want to display it in HH:MM AM format in Ionic

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To display datetime, you can just do it in angular2 way, using a pipe. Angular2 provides a [DatePipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html#!#sts=Pipe). You can use it like this:

```
{{info.createdDate | date: "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"}}
```

[update]

If you want to display as format 'HH:MM AM', just use:

```
{{info.createdDate | date: "shortTime"}}
```

will be fine.

Comment: Question is "HH:MM AM" format. This will display date and 24 hour time format.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

`<ion-datetime displayFormat="hh:mm a" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>`

[Read more here from ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/datetime/DateTime/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "display" it in say a p tag then you can use [momentJs library](http://momentjs.com/)
Otherwise, if you want to load it into the dateTime directive of ionic follow whatever kyle has posted

Answer (score 1):

A good resource is the angular documentation. It is well written check it out here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display as format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm am/pm', just use:

```
{{item.createdDate | date: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm a"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the date string to following function, it will return time in **HH:MM AM** format.

```
getFormatedTime(dateString){
   var date = new Date(dateString);
   var hours = date.getHours() > 12 ? date.getHours() - 12 : date.getHours();
   var am_pm = date.getHours() >= 12 ? "pm" : "am";
   var minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
   let time = hours + ":" + minutes + " " + am_pm;
   return time;
}
```